# How do I get my IP address from inside an ECS container running with the awsvpc network mode?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-vpc

From a regular ECS container running with the bridge mode, or from a standard EC2 instance, I usually run

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

to retrieve my IP.

In an ECS container running with the awsvpc network mode, I get the IP of the underlying EC2 instance which is not what I want. I want the address of the ENI attached to my container. How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A new convenience environment variable is injected by the AWS container agent into every container in AWS ECS: `${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI}`

This contains the URL to the metadata endpoint, so now you can do

```
curl ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI}
```

The output looks something like

```
{  
   "DockerId":"redact",
   "Name":"redact",
   "DockerName":"ecs-redact",
   "Image":"redact",
   "ImageID":"redact",
   "Labels":{  },
   "DesiredStatus":"RUNNING",
   "KnownStatus":"RUNNING",
   "Limits":{  },
   "CreatedAt":"2019-04-16T22:39:57.040286277Z",
   "StartedAt":"2019-04-16T22:39:57.29386087Z",
   "Type":"NORMAL",
   "Networks":[  
      {  
         "NetworkMode":"awsvpc",
         "IPv4Addresses":[  
            "172.30.1.115"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Under the key `Networks` you'll find `IPv4Address`

You application code can then look something like this (python)

```
METADATA_URI = os.environ['ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI']
container_metadata = requests.get(METADATA_URI).json()
ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(container_metadata['Networks'][0]['IPv4Addresses'][0])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only the private IP address but not the public one.